# How to use ajax in zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, jquery

I tried a simple ajax aplication using jquery, where i had my php file in an separate folder in my root and it is working.

Is there any other way to use ajax in a zend framework?

Comment: Please edit your question and make it more readable. And modify your name, to something proper.

Comment: Once you have found an answer that works, please accept that answer, so that other visitors who encounter the same problem, will know which solution works.

Comment: how do i accept? i am new to stack overflow.

Comment: @sarunathan Click on the tick mark near the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways you can do it

1. Use [ZendX_JQuery](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.jquery.html). They have helper called **ajax_link**, with which you can use make ajax call directly from a link.
2. Embed a js file, in your file and use ajax there. Use something like:

   > $this -> headLink() -> appendScript('path/to/your/script');

   You might have to import the JQuery file like this, if you have not enabled this, using the ZendX_JQuery helper.
3. Directly feed script content like `<script>...</script>` like you would raw html

However, JQuery helper might take a bit to fully understand. If you are already familier with JQuery, and know how to use it properly. Go with option number 2.

:)

Comment: Thanks for the response.ill google about zendx_jquery.is there any issue if i link my jquery and use via that?

Comment: when you use ZendX_JQuery, you can include the library, simple with `$this -> JQuery -> enable();`, no need to link. However, this way, zf will use CDN of google.